# Run Vue server in other host

Tags: vue.js, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

I have this question.

Is possible run dev server of Vue in other host? **if not, with my IP address**, with IP address of the another machine.

What i need is, that the broswer recognizes it as safe site. With my IP Address is not working, works with `localhost:8080`

> Sorry if my English is bad, I am new for this

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you want to expose your localhost to the internet (and by extension benefit from testing your development environment with SSL) you can use ngrok.

https://ngrok.com/

While connected to an ngrok tunnel, it transmits any data from a given port on your localhost, through to a public URL you can access from any device.

To achieve this, first you would register for a free ngrok account and install the application.

Next, you'd start up your Vue dev server on localhost.

Lastly, you'd connect ngrok by running `ngrok http 8080`.

This will create an ngrok tunnel from `http://localhost:8080` to a SSL enabled link that you can access on any device you want while your tunnel is running.